# How to get loggedin user session in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I created a module,that show list of user . I want to show that page if user is logged-in admin panel

```
 // world.php



<?php
namespace Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Controller\Hello;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class World extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        var_dump("feererggrerge",$customerSession->isLoggedIn());
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();;
        return $page_object;
    }
}
```

[image: Directory structure]

I want to get admin session in my module controller to check if he is logged in admin panel

Answer (score 1):

You can check user logged in or not using this

Method 1. To check the customer is logged or not on any page of the website:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

   // customer login action

}
```

Method 2.  To check if customer is logged from controller:

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

   // customer login action

}

<?php 
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        //not logged in
    }else{
        // logged in
    }
?>
```

Comment: @  how to check if a customer is logged in admin panel

Comment: Check this Link http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2012/03/30/check-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-inside-magento/

Comment: it is not working , although i doing on server using ssh i am not getting logs for any error so its difficult to debug can you check i have added my code and structure

Comment: You are checking form the controller file. I have updated the answer with the new method to check.

Comment: I want people loggedin through magnto admin panel only it will check for customer also

Comment: i loggedin to my server and it showing me still it showing me false i used menthod1 in my controller i modified the code above please check

Comment: Did you check method 2 that is for the controller

Comment: Please modify the code according to method2 , i am getting errors in that , i am using it with ssh so i dont have even logs  for that